# Customize JBoss CXF WSDL

Tags: web-services, jboss, cxf

I have just installed CXF for JBoss 5.2 instead of the native stack.

1°/ So the new generated wsdl starts with 'wsdl:definitions' instead of 'definitions' when we used the native stack.

Does someone know where to remove this prefix?

2°/ When we send a Soap query to the WS the response starts with:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
```

instead of:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
```

Does someone know where to change this prefix?

**NB**: We don't have any access to the java code, this should be configured in the JBoss configuration files or something like that.

Thanks,

Comment: Why you need to do that? As long as the prefix points to the correct namespace all should work just fine.

Comment: Because I am exposing this WS to a lot of other services and some of them are not working after this upgrade because they are not able to parse the WSDL and/or the Soap response. 

I am not able to change my customers' code or ask them for any change.


I know that if my customers are doing thing in the best way, they will not face an issue to parse this WSDL.

However, I am responsible for this API and this API is not supposed to change...